# Low Yearly Archives always uses channel start & end month

Tags: low-yearly-archives, low

This:

```
{exp:low_yearly_archives channel="blog" status="not closed" monthsort="desc" start_year="{segment_3}" end_year="{segment_3}"}
```

Returns:

- August
- July
- June
- May
- April

for `segment_3`=2008 or `segment_3`=2009.

even though 2009 has posts the entire year. It's filtering the results based on the first entry month and last entry month across *all* years even when I use `start_year` and `end_year` params. It should check first & last month within the requested range of years.

I'm using the latest version, downloaded 2 days ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Current behaviour is that both `start_month` and `end_month` are separate from the `start_year` and `end_year`. The month params will still default to the first and last month in the given entries, regardless of year.

Try adding `start_month="01"` and `end_month="12"` to the tag. I'll mark it as a feature request to make this a bit more intuitive.

Comment: Thanks, Low! That's what I did as a workaround. Agreed that it's a feature request/bug report more than a support Q, but this was the prominent go-to on your site.